# react : Ride property to the parent

Tags: reactjs

i'm developing in React. I have a button submit code of a form in my form component.

```
public handleSubmit = () => {                      
                this.props.addItem({ id: this.refs.id.getValue()}

    }
```

I would like to send this code on its parent component, to place  the submit button  elsewhere. 
So, I think I must to declare a property on my form component. But I don't know how to call this code on parent componenent. How can I do that ? 
Thank you

Comment: Read [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) to learn how to properly implement parent/child communication.

Comment: Also, this is irrelevant to the question, but - you shouldn't be using refs to get data from form fields. Read the [Forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) section of the docs for more info.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice, i'm going to read that, and I ask you question if i have a problem